# Observable's Correct explanation in rxjava and rxandroid

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2, rx-android

What are the correct concepts and working of `observables` and observers in `RxJava`. I get confused by the words literal  meaning. Whenever I change the values of `observables` its corresponding observers is not getting invoked i.e. I will explain this situation a bit more deeply, initially when I assign an `observable` with a list of strings(List  list) and subscribe it to an observer, observer works perfectly  but after that ,when I change the values of list(for example adding more String values to list) ...the observer's on next  should automatically be invoked right.. but it isn't. Trying to implement in **Android natively** . I will be happy for some helps.

Comment: There are no notification mechanisms included in Java `List`s, so changing them can't signal new items in observers. Please provide more context and code about what you try to achieve and what have you so far.

Answer (score 1):

`Observables` work with three methods from `Observer`: `onNext`, `onError` and `onCompleted`. When you make `Observable` from a list and you subscribe it Observable will emit those values using `onNext` method and when it's finished it will call `onCompleted` method.

You can't change values that Observable is emitting by changing list you gave to some Observable operator. What would be you desired behaviour. Should `Observable` emit all elements on list change or should it emit only new changes.

This observable will emit all changes to collection made trough `setCollection` method:

```
public class CollectionObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {

    private Collection<T> collection;
    private List<Observer<? super T>> observers;

    public CollectionObservable(Collection<T> collection) {
        if (collection != null) {
            this.collection = collection;
        }
        this.observers = new ArrayList<>(2);
    }

    public Collection<T> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }

    public void setCollection(Collection<T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
        emitValuesToAllObserver();
    }

    public void complete() {
        if (this.collection != null) {
            for (Observer<? super T> observer : this.observers) {
                observer.onComplete();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
        this.observers.add(observer);
        emitValues(observer);
    }

    private void emitValuesToAllObserver() {
        for (Observer<? super T> observer : this.observers) {
            emitValues(observer);
        }
    }

    private void emitValues(Observer<? super T> observer) {
        if (this.collection != null) {
            for (T obj : this.collection) {
                observer.onNext(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in order to finish you manually have to call `complete` method.

Comment: Tags specify `rxjava2`, so your answer is missing the `onSubscribe` call that is required before any calls to `onNext`.